# Reload div's content from x to x seconds using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, loops, laravel-5

I'm developing an app using Laravel 5 and I'm currently struggling at trying to reload the div's content without having to reload the page.

**What I want to achieve:**
Change a div's content from x to x seconds without the need of reloading the page, this process needs to be endlessly looped

The div's content will be randomly chosen from the models sent by the controller.

Here's a Controller Example:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {
   public function index()
   {
       $informations = Information::all();
       return view('\', compact('informations'));
   }
}
```

Now in the view, the div's content should change every x seconds, picking a random Model from `$informations` in order to show it's content, looping endlessly.

I tried to give as much information as I could since as this somewhat difficult to explain, please ask anything if needed to help coming up with a solution.